Highlight areas of interactive time series plotly plot where y is greater than defined threshold and annotate them
I would like to highlight sections of plotly plot that have values higher than a certain threshold and annotate them. As I am manually screening each highlighted area on the plots is there a way I can add the text Pos or Neg individually to each highlighted area on the plotly plot?
# Load packages
library(xts)
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotly)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout

# Create time series data every 15 minutes for 2 different variables
start_time <- as.POSIXct("2024-05-01 00:00:00")
end_time <- as.POSIXct("2024-05-02 00:00:00")
time_seq <- seq(from = start_time, to = end_time, by = "15 min")

# Variable 1
variable1 <- rnorm(length(time_seq), mean = 25, sd = 5)
variable1
#>  [1] 19.64150 21.91925 30.26140 24.73885 15.62106 24.42389 23.66606 29.51821
#>  [9] 28.73607 29.74207 27.91748 30.50421 22.87791 21.98245 24.62681 26.63759
#> [17] 35.72062 25.35210 24.80731 11.10508 23.51079 16.52044 27.82598 22.25517
#> [25] 22.91079 29.21557 25.83038 28.42228 21.08665 19.49110 19.08057 27.76373
#> [33] 27.79809 34.81478 19.66126 29.43602 27.07366 30.06237 17.23155 22.55079
#> [41] 23.93064 22.00335 28.37549 19.24512 17.07143 24.20822 17.40344 16.85957
#> [49] 22.63171 14.34134 23.23399 25.18874 16.35321 22.83617 21.86500 26.76390
#> [57] 21.45600 35.34945 19.06585 18.04736 15.99879 32.98314 28.72129 23.41016
#> [65] 25.32476 24.55138 29.47520 16.39592 23.14157 21.38850 19.58153 23.72860
#> [73] 26.21399 27.22447 23.78197 23.12036 29.35689 25.86351 25.20781 22.89124
#> [81] 32.17681 36.02693 23.75858 20.67829 28.79505 19.32367 23.73758 25.86511
#> [89] 18.71596 28.19968 16.28308 24.59351 30.57592 25.06673 29.30346 35.90666
#> [97] 29.07116
str(variable1)
#>  num [1:97] 19.6 21.9 30.3 24.7 15.6 ...

# Variable 2
variable2 <- rnorm(length(time_seq), mean = 350, sd = 20)

# Create dataframe of the 2 variables
df <- data.frame(DateTime = time_seq, Variable1 = variable1, Variable2 = variable2)
head(df)
#>              DateTime Variable1 Variable2
#> 1 2024-05-01 00:00:00  19.64150  331.8194
#> 2 2024-05-01 00:15:00  21.91925  360.4271
#> 3 2024-05-01 00:30:00  30.26140  343.6143
#> 4 2024-05-01 00:45:00  24.73885  362.8967
#> 5 2024-05-01 01:00:00  15.62106  355.4895
#> 6 2024-05-01 01:15:00  24.42389  347.0129
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    97 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ DateTime : POSIXct, format: "2024-05-01 00:00:00" "2024-05-01 00:15:00" ...
#>  $ Variable1: num  19.6 21.9 30.3 24.7 15.6 ...
#>  $ Variable2: num  332 360 344 363 355 ...



# Highlight areas on the plot where Variable 1 > 28.3
plot_var1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = DateTime, y = Variable1))+
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_rect(data = subset(df, Variable1 > 28.3),
  aes(xmin = DateTime-450, xmax = DateTime+450, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
  fill = "lightblue", alpha = 0.3) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Variable 1")
plot_var1


# Highlight areas on the plot where Variable 2 is between 335 and 390
plot_var2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = DateTime, y = Variable2)) +
  geom_line(color = "red") +
  geom_rect(data = subset(df, Variable2 > 335 & Variable2 < 390),
            aes(xmin = DateTime-450, xmax = DateTime+450, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            fill = "lightpink", alpha = 0.3) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Variable 2") +
  theme_minimal()
plot_var2


# Arrange plots in one column and align by x-axis
Comb_Var1_Var2_Highlight_Plot<-grid.arrange(plot_var1, plot_var2, ncol = 1)



# Interactive Plot for Variable 1
Int_plot_Var1<-ggplotly(plot_var1)

# Interactive plot for Variable 2
Int_plot_Var2<-ggplotly(plot_var2)
Created on 2024-07-17 with reprex v2.1.0

When I create the plotly plot the highlighted areas do not appear.  Can I add them to plotly plot?

I only just came across your question last night, I hope this still helps.
There are a few things going on here from the conversion between ggplot and plotly

dates are no longer dates - generally just numbers
the x-axis is static, because it's assigned category names for specific values
Plotly fills and plotly lines don't really play well together (using shapes works better for this)

You can create the shapes using the same data that you used in geom_rect using purrr::map.
library(tidyverse) # replaced ggplot2 for purr & ggplot2
library(plotly)

shps <- map(1:nrow(subset(df, Variable1 > 28.3)), \(k) {
  dta <- subset(df, Variable1 > 28.3)    # create data used in geom_rect
  list(type = "rect",                    # define shape for Plotly
       xref = "x", yref = "paper",       # use x axis, not y axis
       x0 = dta$DateTime[k] - 450,       # where on x
       x1 = dta$DateTime[k] + 450,
       y0 = 0, y1 = 1,                   # where on plot (versus y)
       fillcolor = "lightblue", opacity = .3, line = list(width = 0))
})

You can address the numbers-that-are-not-dates-anymore issue with a fixer() function, going through the data in plot and updating the variable type.
fixer <- function(plt) {  
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)              # make sure entire plot built
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data), \(k) {   # go through each trace (layer) 
    plt$x$data[[k]]$x <<- as.POSIXct(plt$x$data[[k]]$x) # update x-axis data type
  })
  plt
}

When you apply these elements to the plot, you need to make sure the other presets assigned in the conversion are not going to get in your way:

x-axis' tick mode, type and whether it's autorange or not
remove the shape that's not a shape --- why or why Plotly? (or is it ggplot??)

Here's how to put that all together.
ggplotly(plot_var1) %>%             # prep xaxis for dates
  layout(xaxis = list(tickmode = "auto", type = "date", autorange = T),
         shapes = NA) %>%           # remove migration garbage
  fixer() %>%                       # fix dates - make them dates again
  layout(shapes = shps)             # add new shapes


Alternatively...as you have identified 2 plots...
This may be something that's better applied dynamically. (Dynamic-ish...still relies on a lot of assumptions..)
This combines all of the concepts above into one plot. Instead of using the methods you used in your call to geom_rect, it pulls the data in the ggplot object.
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

fixer <- function(plt) {  
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)              # make sure entire plot built
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data), \(k) {   # go through each trace (layer) 
    plt$x$data[[k]]$x <<- as.POSIXct(plt$x$data[[k]]$x) # update x-axis data type
  })
  plt
}

tSpan <- function(gplt) {  # gplt: ggplot graph to be made into a ggplotly 
  #  - assuming one x-axis within gplt
  #  - assuming geom_rect called 2nd in gplt
  
  # 2 here, because geom_rect was called 2nd            --- get data from plot
  dta <- data.frame(ggplot_build(gplt)$data[[2]][c("xmin", "xmax", "fill", "alpha")]) %>% 
    mutate(xmin = as.POSIXct(xmin), xmax = as.POSIXct(xmax))

  shps <- map(1:nrow(dta), \(k) {    # create data used in geom_rect
    list(type = "rect", xref = "x", yref = "paper",  # define shape, use x axis, not y axis
         x0 = dta$xmin[k], x1 = dta$xmax[k],         # where on x
         y0 = 0, y1 = 1,                             # where on plot (versus y)
                                                     # update aesthetics
         fillcolor = dta$fill[1], opacity = dta$alpha[1], line = list(width = 0))
    })
  
  ggplotly(gplt) %>%              # pre xaxis for dates
    layout(xaxis = list(tickmode = "auto", type = "date", autorange = T),
           shapes = NA) %>%            # remove migration garbage
    fixer() %>%                        # fix dates - make them dates again
    layout(shapes = shps)              # add new shapes
}

tSpan(plot_var2)
tSpan(plot_var1)


